# Python : Remove tag and replace \u00a0 in json file

Tags: python, html, json, unicode

I have json file like this :

```
[
    {
       "content": ["<p style=\"text-align:justify;\"> This is content1</p>"],
       "title" : ["This is\u00a0title 1"]
    },
    {
       "content": ["<p style=\"text-align:justify;\"> This is content2</p>"],
       "title" : ["This is\u00a0title 2"]
    }
]
```

i want my json like this :

```
[
        {
           "content": ["This is content1"],
           "title" : ["This is title 1"]
        },
        {
           "content": ["This is content2"],
           "title" : ["This is title 2"]
        }
    ]
```

i want to remove HTML tag and also replace \u00a0 with " ".
How to do it?

Comment: So what is the expected output? What have you tried yourself so far, where did you get stuck?

Comment: @MartijnPieters i have already edit it

Comment: There are plenty of answers here that show how to strip HTML from a string, or how to replace a certain character with another (here it is a newline with a space). *These problems have been solved*. Have you looked up those answers? What problems did you encounter when you tried to apply them?

Answer (score 0):

Start with the Python [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). That will allow you to read and write the JSON string into Python data structures. Then use the normal Python tools to process the data.

To process the HTML, look at [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).